# Is alarmmanager ALWAYS cleared after reboot?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, reboot, bootcompleted

Simple question: is the `AlarmManager` ***always*** cleared after reboot? Is it cleared after reboot on all devices and even when the user boots his device up very shortly after he booted it off?

I need to know this because I recreate my app's alarm in an `OnBootReceiver` and I want to avoid having double alarms set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is the AlarmManager always cleared after reboot?

Definitely on a full reboot. There are some devices that have a "quickboot" (HTC comes to mind), and I have not run experiments to see what the behavior is there.

> and even when the user boots his device up very shortly after he booted it off?

Yes.

> I need to know this because I recreate my app's alarm in an OnBootReceiver and I want to avoid having double alarms set.

Alarms are effectively in a `HashMap` keyed by `PendingIntent`. Setting an alarm using an equivalent `PendingIntent` should replace the prior alarm. By "equivalent", I mean:

- Same operation (activity, service, broadcast)
- Same request code
- Equivalent `Intent` (matches via `filterEquals()`, which pretty much means it matches on everything except the extras)
- And I'd be nervous about using `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` when defining the new `PendingIntent`

You can use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to confirm what alarms are set, so you are sure that you wind up with the right number of alarms.

Comment: So would it perhaps be a good idea to call `cancel()` first in the OnBootReceiver and after that call `set()`?

Comment: @Merlin: Personally, I am not aware of any scenario in which that is required. For example, the HTC quickboot does not trigger `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`. That being said, you are certainly welcome to do so -- `cancel()` should not have an issue if there is no existing alarm for that `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Yeah well, my OnBootReceiver receives `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` as well (in case the alarms are cancelled in quickboot), so I'll just cancel it before setting it. Thank you for your help!